# vue how to mock my external service class

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

In my vue component , in the mounted i am calling a service class which in turn invokes axios call ..like below

```js
import StudentService from '../utils/student.services'
    
export default {
  name: 'student-summary',
    
  mounted () {
    console.log('%c FeeMdoule-Data Recieved on Mount as %s', 'color: blue ;font-size : 12px', JSON.stringify(this.filingData))
    StudentService.getDetails().then(data => {
      this.sList = data
    })
  },
  // ...
}
```

I have now written JEST test cases of the vue component and i have mocked axios within vue component test cases..
But i think the right approach is to mock the studentServices rather than not mock axios directly from component...

How to mock the studentservices from the vue compoent test and not have any axios in the test case of my vue component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jest documents describe class mocks [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks)

**StudentService.spec.js**

```js
import StudentService from '../utils/student.services'
    
jest.mock('../utils/student.services');
    
describe("StudentService", () => {
  let mockDetails = [{ studentId: 1 }]
  StudentService.getDetails = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockDetails);
    
  afterEach(() => {
    // reset mock after each test
    StudentService.getDetails.mockReset();
  });
    
  it("should get details", () => {
    // ... mount your component
    expect(StudentService.getDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
    
});
```